# Kubernetes Dashboard - How to lock down 8080 access

Tags: security, kubernetes, port, dashboard

I currently have kubernetes dashboard installed and I can access the dashboard via http://ip-address:8080/ui and also https://ip-address:443/ui. The latter asks for a username and password and I'm able to log into the K8s dashboard.

Question: What do I have to change to lock down 8080? I do not want people be able to access the dashboard via port 8080.

I tried changing the kubernetes-dashboard.yaml file from port 80 to 443 and targetport: 9090 to 8443, but it tells me the dashboard service cannot be found if I try to access it via HTTPS (port 443). Any advice would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default ports with `--insecure-port` flag as explained in documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/

Comment: I had to specify the --insecure-bind-address to a local IP